# Shell stderr redirection to another file using a text file as a argument

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I wrote a bash script which would read the text file already provided in the argument and would process the text and redirect errors to the error file and other outputs to the list.txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read line; do
        a=$(echo $line | awk "{print NF}")
                if [ "$a" = "3" ]
                then
                        first=$(echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
                        last=$(echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
                        email=$(echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $3}')
                        if [[ $first =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ && $last =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
                        then
                                if [[ $email =~ '<([\w\.\-_]+)?\w+@[\w-_]+(\.\w+){1,}>' ]]
                                then
                                        echo "$first $last $email" | cat >>list.txt
                                elif [[ $email =~ '([\w\.\-_]+)?\w+@[\w-_]+(\.\w+){1,}' ]]
                                then
                                        echo "$first $last <$email>" | cat >>list.txt
                                else
                                        echo "$first $last $email" | cat >&2
                                fi
                        else
                                echo "$first $last $email" | cat >&2
                        fi
                else
                        echo "$line" | cat >&2
                fi
        done < $filename
```

I run this code as $./script.sh argumentfile.txt 2>error.txt

My argument file has following information

```
Joe cable cable@ablecorp.com
Bob Brown <bob_baker@bakerandsons.com>
Jim Hass  hass@bigcorp.com
mike_lupo@mou.east.com
Edison jones jones@inl.net.gov
pirate.coe.su.com pirate people
```

Ideal form of the file should be as (which is intentionally poorly formatted)

```
lastname firstname <email>
```

In the error file what I get is

```
 Joe cable cable@ablecorp.com
Bob Brown <bob_baker@bakerandsons.com>
Jim Hass  hass@bigcorp.com
mike_lupo@mou.east.com
Edison jones jones@inl.net.gov
pirate.coe.su.com pirate people
```

Comment: `echo ... | cat` is pointless. You don't need the pipeline or `cat`.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script so you see what is actually being run and try to figure out which pattern isn't matching and then you might be able to figure out why.

Comment: it seem like you have problem with the regex, check it using the command -  [[ $email =~ $reg ]] && echo "yes!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this entirely with `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk '{

name_re = "^[[:alpha:]]+$"
mail_re = "<?[[:alnum:]_.%+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\\.[[:alpha:]]{2,6}>?"

# check for 3 fields with suitable regexp matching for all
if (NF == 3 && $1 ~ name_re && $2 ~ name_re && $3 ~ mail_re) {
    # put brackets around the address if needed
    email = $3 ~ /^<.*?>$/ ? $3 : "<" $3 ">"
    # output to the good list
    print $1 " " $2 " " email > "list.txt"
    # move to the next one
    next
}

# output to the bad list
print > "error.txt"

}' "$1"
```

Tested with BSD and Gnu versions of `awk`.

Comment: Thank you, your code it works, I actually made few changes and it is working for me as well

`if [[ $email =~ [a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4}) ]]`

Comment: Except your bash script is a mess, and you're already calling `awk` 4 times. You'll find that the fewer commands, pipes, and subshells are present in your script, the faster it will run.